# Is there a generalization of Jordan curve theorem? Not in higher dimension, but in the plane?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples

> **Jordan curve theorem** (bit generalized one)
>
> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be closed connected subsets of $S^2$ whose intersection consists of two points. If neither $C_1$ nor $C_2$ separates $S^2$, then $C_1\cup C_2$ separates $S^2$ into precisely two components.

I think the above theorem can be generalized further and below is the statement I formulated:

> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be closed connected subsets of $S^2$ whose intersection is a **disjoint union** of two nonempty connected compact subsets. If neither $C_1$ nor $C_2$ separates $S^2$, then $C_1\cup C_2$ separates $S^2$ into precisely two components.

Is this true? If so how do I prove this? Or else if this is false, what would be a counterexample?

Comment: Use Alexander duality and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $C_1, C_2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that $H_1(S^2\setminus C_1\cap C_2)\ne 0$ using Mayer–Vietoris sequence, and then use Mayer–Vietoris sequence again for the pair $S^2\setminus C_1$, $S^2\setminus C_2$ and show that rank of $H_0(S^2\setminus(C_1\cup C_2))$ is at least two.

Comment: really, as user _anomaly_ advised in his deleted answer, the statement "$H_1(S^2\setminus C_1\cap C_2)\ne 0$" can be proved using Alexander duality instead Mayer–Vietoris sequence.

Comment: no, it turns out that here Alexander duality fails, because it needs to $C_1\cap C_2$ be locally contractible. instead this we should use Mayer–Vietoris for the complements of $S^2$ to the two components of $C_1\cap C_2$.

Comment: No, the duality does not fail: Just use the Chech cohomology instead of singular cohomology; this eliminates the need for local connectivity.